# Mathematical induction: $n^4 + n$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

Question: $n^4 + n$ is even for all Natural number.

I got all the way to where Basis step is $n=1$ and Inductive step is $k^4 + k$ (evens)

If my goal is to find $(k+1)^4 + (k+1)$, how would I get there?

Comment: Do you need to solve by induction?

Comment: If you were instructed to do it by induction you probably should, and it certainly can be done by induction. It’s important to learn how to do proofs by induction cause it is a useful proof strategy. But also worthy to observe that we simply have two case two check, what happens when $n$ is even and what happens when $n$ is odd. If $n$ is even $n^4$ is even but the sum of two even numbers is even so $n^4 + n$ is even. If $n$ is odd then $n^4$ is odd and the sum of two odd numbers is even so $n^4 + n$ is even.

Comment: Thinking of it this way, we immediately see it didn’t matter that we had exponent 4 and exponent 1, so we can say $n^i + n^j$ is even for any natural $n$ and any naturals $i,j  \geq 1$. Further, now you might notice it doesn’t matter how many summands we have, so we can generalize to any finite sum where summands are of the form $n^i$ for a fixed natural $n$ (or at least naturals of the same parity) and naturals $i \geq 1$

Comment: Another way of seeing this is that $n^4+n=n(n+1)(n^2-n+1)$ has factors which include two consecutive integers, one of which must be even. But I guess it is practice at induction. Factorising is not the best method for this problem because it doesn't capture the full generality of @PrinceM 's comment. But, for example, it works a treat for showing that $n^3-n$ is divisible by $6$ - so I thought you might be interested.

Comment: @MarkBennet when I first started typing my comment I was going to factor as $n(n^3 + 1)$ to yield the same argument (one factor odd, one factor even), but then I thought, do we even need to factor this at all? Glad that between are comments and solutions below OP now has seen three separate ways to approach the problem and the advantages of each, and has been advised that it is important to learn induction for its own sake! :)

Comment: @jamesMadison Please recall that if the OP is solved you can evaluate to accept an answer among the given, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 5):

**HINT**

Note that

$$(k+1)^4+(k+1)=k^4+4k^3+6k^2+5k+2=(k^4+k)+4k^3+6k^2+4k+2$$

Answer (score 4):

$(k+1)^4 + (k+1) = k^4 + 4k^3 + 6k^2 + 4k + 1 + k + 1 = k^4 + k + 2(2k^3 + 3k^2 + 2k + 1)$ what is even, on condition that $k^4 + k$ is even (assumption in induction proof)

Answer (score 3):

Just expand it out
\begin{eqnarray*}
(k+1)^4+(k+1)= \underbrace{k^4+k}_{\text{Even by the I.H.}}+\color{red}{4}k^3+\color{red}{6}k^2+\color{red}{4}k+\color{red}{2}.
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: You've made an error in expanding - the constant term on the left is 1 but on the right you've got 2.

Comment: @B.Mehta Oh i see, sorry about that

Comment: @TheIntegrator B.Mehta was correct for the previous edit ... sorry for not commenting. ... but hey Happy Birthday to me (yesterday).

Comment: even tho the comment section isnt a place to say it , Happy birthday @DonaldSplutterwit Hope you had a nice one and many more to come

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is an exercise, but induction is overkill here.
Just remark that $n$ and $n^k$ have same parity for any integer $k$.

Thus their sum $n^k+n$ is even.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed... what's the problem?  If $n$ is even, then $n^4$ is even so $n^4 + n$ is even.  If $n$ is odd, then $n^4$ is odd, so $n^4 + n$ is even.

$\square$